# Where is the square bracket [Type] syntax documented?

Tags: typescript

I came across [this line](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-common/blob/6b0ff68b520f975cfcf889af7e1cec8e5dc8d34f/src/service-object.ts#L263) in of code in a Google library:

```
delete(options?: DeleteOptions): Promise<[r.Response]>;
```

and was surprised to see the brackets around `r.Response`. I am familiar with two ways of specifying a list in Typescript:

- `baseType[]`
- `Array<baseType>`

But, to date, I had not seen `[baseType]` in the language docs. What is this syntax? Where is this documented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3.3.3

As of Typescript 1.4, `Array literals may be used to create values of tuple types`.

In this case there is only one type, which is a little strange, but still perfectly valid.

Comment: Oh, so this is a unary tuple?

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't make much sense but is possibly for future compatible extensibility

Comment: Ah okay thanks a lot. So strange, did not even occur to me.

Comment: And yes, maybe future extensibility? But if you look at the callback variant, the callback's signature is a non-tupled `(err, r.Response)`. Funky...